# Let a Paypal donation change CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, paypal

I'm a beginner at coding but I couldn't find the answer on the internet.

I have a browser game with a donate button from Paypal. After someone has done a donation, he goes to the thankyou-page.

I want to give the people who have donated a little golden crown (an svg) in the game, and I tried to do that with this when pressing the "go back to homepage and get a crown" button on the thankyou-page:

```
document.getElementById('crown').style.display = "inherit";
```

(the display according to the css was "none")

But the thing is: It doesn't work (it must be because I have 2 different .html files with 2 different .js files, because when I use one .js file for both of the .html files it gives many errors of things that are not working).

The main thing is: I want to give something visually back to the people who donated. Is there a simple solution to do this?

index.html where the crown is:

```
<svg id="crown">
  Some svg coordinates that form a crown
</svg>
```

style.css where it is invisible:

```
#crown {
  display: none;
}
```

A button in index.html has a Paypal link where you can donate. When you have donated, you land on thankyou.html with this button on it:

```
<button id="getCrown" type="button" 
onclick="window.location.href='/index.html'; getCrown();">Give me that crown!</button>
```

That should let the Javascript in thankyou.js make the crown visible with this:

```
document.getElementById('crown').style.display = "inherit";
```

But it doesn't. It gives an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
at getCrown (thankyou.js:5)
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (thankyou.html:32)
```

Comment: Hey Chris! it would be a little bit easier for us to help you out if we could see what you have tried so far or event better if you could try and recreate your issue on https://jsfiddle.net/ and share a link with us

Comment: It really depends on how you are handling the code (which is why @AwadMaharoof asked for it - really is pretty important if you want help....) - though I'm guessing you will have some sort of "user profile" code - why not add a "hasCrown" element in there and turn it on when the donation hits?  Another thought (depending on code...) is to turn it on through css in the Paypal return.....  Well, as you can see, we could guess all day - so show some code bits and you will get detailed help!

Comment: This is likely something you'll want to send over from the server side in order to perform verifications on the donation, as well as if you'll want other users to see said crown.

Comment: Maybe a case for a session? Either serverside or just something like sessionStorage or in this case probaly better localStorage. But still the user could delete the storage so serveside session would be better if you even have a user-login system because if not you have to you client-side storage.

Comment: I don't have a user-login system @TheFool but how would you do it with localStorage?

Comment: @ChrisNooitgedagt you add an item to the users local storage in his browser when he donates. And then you simple say if a user has this item with the right value in his browser then he can see the crown. (with javascript). Like this for example: `localStorage.setItem('crown', 'visible');` but be careful because he can clear his local storage and then you have no way knowing if he donated or not and he wont see the crown. Thats why a login system would be handy so u could pass the information as cookie for example.  check out: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you give your button a `onclick="set_crown()"` attribute.
This calls the set_crown() javascript function:

```
function set_crown(){
localStorage.setItem('crown', 'visible');
};
```

then you check in your index html if he got this key with the right value  with javascript like this:

```
if (localStorage.getItem('crown') === 'visible'){
document.getElementById('crown').style.display = 'inherit';
};
```

Note that you can do the same with sessionStorage. The difference is that localStorage data will stay there untill the user clears his browser or you delete it with javascript while sessionStorage will clear itself when the session ends aka the browser closes.

Here again something to read ;) [localStorage info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Here the two little example pages:

index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head><meta charset="utf-8"></head>

  <body onload="check_crown()">

    <div id="crown" style="display:none">
      <p>I am a Crown :)</p>
    </div>

    <button id="donate" type="button"
            onclick="window.location.href='thankyou.html';">
            Donate
    </button>

    <script type="text/javascript">

       function check_crown(){
         if (localStorage.getItem('crown') === 'visible'){
           document.getElementById('crown').style.display = 'inherit';
         };

       };
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

thankyou.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head><meta charset="utf-8"></head>
  <body>

    <button id="getCrown" type="button"
            onclick="window.location.href='index.html'; set_crown();">
            Give me that crown!
    </button>


    <script type="text/javascript">

      function set_crown(){
        localStorage.setItem('crown', 'visible');
      };
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Simply run the index with your favorite browser, Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll try things out.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have two different document objects i.e. the thankyou.html & index.html. So as part of your event handling (in context of thankyou document) you're trying to alter the state of another document (index.html). This is not something you want to do.
I have tried to create a fiddle out of your example and it works fine with a single document model. https://jsfiddle.net/8y4jdapt/20/
See if it helps.

Otherwise, why don't you pass on a URL parameter to index.html like `window.location.href='/index.html?showCrown=true` And use this parameter somwhere in the context of index.html to decide whether to render the crown or not.

Comment: Why does the button in your fiddle change position when it is clicked? I don't see the code for that.

Comment: Because when you click the button `display` style is dynamically added to crown element which was invisible until now.

Comment: I still don't get it. I'm a beginner at coding, as you might have assumed. I also don't get your solution of the URL parameter. Do you mean that I can't have a thankyou-page? Or do I have to make a thankyou-page inside the index.html (and how would I do that)?